# When i am deploying shopizer.war in tomcat i am getting below error

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, shopizer

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance 
    of   
    class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
    Error creating bean with name 'categoryDao': Injection of
    persistence dependencies failed; nested exception 
    is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException:
    Error loading class [com.shopizer.modules.shipping.distance.
    ShippingDistancePreProcessorImpl] for 
    bean with name 'shippingDistancePreProcessor' defined 
    in class path resource 
    [spring/processors/shopizer-core-shipping-processors.xml]: 
    problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception 
    is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  
    com/salesmanager/
    core/modules/integration/shipping/model/
    ShippingQuotePrePostProcessModule
    Related cause: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
    Error     loading class
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to answer based on the stack trace above,

but I see a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  , which is an indication that you are mising a dependency at run time. I'm not sure how your project is set up , but check you container settings for missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have defined all the beans in your version of the spring-config.xml and in case if you are Autowiring annotations, please check if your bean classes are annotated.